# How do I update Ember CLI record with rails 4 Grape API with PUT?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a Rails 4 app setup with a [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) API and an Ember CLI app for the fronted by following [this](https://devmynd.com/blog/2014-7-rails-ember-js-with-the-ember-cli-redux-part-2-the-front-end-with-ember-and-the-ember-cli) tutorial built using the `ActiveModelAdapter`. Everything is working correctly in getting data from the API, but I'm having issues sending POST or PUT requests to the API to create or edit records.
I found another tutorial that shows an example, which uses a `RESTAdapter` and a different API, of how to create the remaining CRUD operations. I'm having some trouble getting the PUT or POST requests to have the appropriate form, I think. Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
    PUT http://localhost:3000/api/v1/contacts/3 400 (Bad Request)jQuery.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.js:9665jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:9216ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.ajax @ inflector.js:30initializePromise @ ember.debug.js:45487Promise @ ember.debug.js:47115ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.ajax @ inflector.js:30ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.updateRecord @ rest-adapter.js:687ember$data$lib$system$store$$_commit @ debug-adapter.js:109(anonymous function) @ store.js:1627forEach @ ember.debug.js:12012ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.flushPendingSave @ store.js:1611Queue.invoke @ ember.debug.js:879Queue.flush @ ember.debug.js:944DeferredActionQueues.flush @ ember.debug.js:749Backburner.end @ ember.debug.js:174Backburner.run @ ember.debug.js:229run @ ember.debug.js:15864ActionHelper.registerAction.ActionManager.default.registeredActions.(anonymous function).handler @ ember.debug.js:18409(anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:36725jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4671jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4339
ember.debug.js:26511 Error: Bad Request
    at ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.ajaxError (inflector.js:6)
    at superFunction [as _super] (ember.debug.js:13812)
    at ember$data$lib$adapters$rest$adapter$$default.extend.ajaxError (json-serializer.js:75)
    at apply (ember.debug.js:17855)
    at superWrapper [as ajaxError] (ember.debug.js:17437)
    at ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.ajax.Ember.RSVP.Promise.hash.error (inflector.js:30)
    at jQuery.Callbacks.fire (jquery.js:3149)
    at Object.jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3261)
    at done (jquery.js:9317)
    at XMLHttpRequest.jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback (jquery.js:9719)
```

Here's my adapter.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ENV from "../config/environment";

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api/v1',
    host: ENV.host
});
```

Here's my router.js:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
    import config from './config/environment';

    var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
      location: config.locationType
    });


    Router.map(function() {
      this.route('dashboard', function() {
          this.resource('contacts', function() {
              this.route('new');
              this.route('show', { path: '/:contact_id' });
              this.route('edit', {path: '/:contact_id/edit'});
            });
        });
    });

export default Router;
```

Here's my contacts/edit.js route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {return this.store.find('contact', params.contact_id);},
    actions: {
        save: function() {  
            var self = this;
            self.controller.get('model').save().then(
                function() {
                    self.transitionTo('contacts.index');
                });
        },
        delete: function() {
            var self = this;
            var model = self.controller.get('model'); 
            model.destroyRecord().then(
                function() {
                    self.transitionTo('contacts.index');
                }, function (error) {
                    Ember.Logger.debug(error);
                });
        }
    }
});
```

I believe the problem is somewhere between the edit router and the adapter... But I'm having trouble identifying exactly what the problem is here.

**UPDATE 1:**
Rails Log outputs:
`Started PUT "/api/v1/contacts/3" for ::1 at 2015-07-13 10:47:04 -0800`

Any help/ideas would be much appreciated!!

Comment: What's the rails log say?

Comment: I added rails log info above, output is just: `Started PUT "/api/v1/contacts/3" for ::1 at 2015-07-13 10:47:04 -0800` seems correct to me?

Comment: That log doesn't show the response code from the server.   I'm wondering if it's the server throwing the 400 error.  Have you tested your backend with something like postman or curl?

Comment: Yeah, it's getting a 400 error... That's the first line of the console output (first code section above)... I think there is some kind of formatting or parsing issue in the API controller. I'm also thinking it might not like the camel case variable name... I'll add my API controller code when I'm back in front of my computer

Comment: I'm just not convinced based on what you've posted so far this isn't a backend issue, have you ruled that out and tested the backend with something other than ember?

Comment: I was able to locate the problem based on your suggestion to look at the the API on the rails side... Turns out I had to reformat the `put` action in the API controller... I'd like to give you credit for the answer. If you'd like to answer the question I'll edit it and add the code that worked for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds more like a backend issue than an ember issue.  Check that your backend is properly responding to requests  (Either via logs, or testing with postman, curl, etc)